# Lagrangian multipliers with complex valued vectors and matrices

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers, lagrange-multiplier

I have a Hermitian matrix $H=H^\dagger$, and some complex matrix $B$ (not Hermitian).
I want to do the following:
$$minimize\ \ \ \ \xi^\dagger H\  \xi$$
$$s.t.\ \ \ \  \ \xi^\dagger B\xi=0,\ \xi^\dagger\xi=1$$
In order to solve I want to use Lagrange multipliers, and vary with respect to $\xi^\dagger$:
$$(H-\mu B)\xi=\lambda\xi$$
Where $\mu,\ \lambda$ are Lagrange multipliers.
The problem is I am not sure about if I can do that because $\xi^\dagger B\xi$ is not  a real function outside of the restricted plane.
So, The question is: Can I use Lagrange multipliers like this? 
If not, would the answer change if  $B$ were a real matrix?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

btw - I know I can just replace the condition to $\xi^\dagger\ (B+B^\dagger)\xi=0$, but the note in the top answer to this question: [Lagrangian multipliers in complex optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182625/lagrangian-multipliers-in-complex-optimization) made me think it is not neccesary. If not I wonder whats working there that is not working here

Answer (score 1):

Considering $\xi = \xi_r+j\xi_i$ and $B = B_r+jB_i$

we have

$$
(\xi_r+j\xi_i)^{\dagger}(B_r+jB_i)(\xi_r+j\xi_i)= \xi_r^{\top} B_r \xi_r+\xi_i^{\top} B_r\xi_i + j(\xi_r^{\top} B_i\xi_r+\xi_r^{\top} B_i\xi_r) = 0
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\xi_r^{\top} B_r \xi_r+\xi_i^{\top} B_r\xi_i = 0\\
\xi_r^{\top} B_i\xi_r+\xi_r^{\top} B_i\xi_r = 0
$$

The stationary conditions are

$$
\xi^{\dagger}H+\lambda_1 \xi^{\dagger}B+\lambda_2\xi^{\dagger} = 0
$$

or

$$
\xi^{\dagger}(H+\lambda_1 B+\lambda_2 I)=0
$$

Those conditions can be established over $\xi_r,\xi_i$ instead. The multipliers $\lambda_k = \lambda_{kr}+j\lambda_{ki}$

Comment: First you got some $i$'s instead of $r's$ in several places. Second I can not see why your second line is correct - you suppose to have mix terms like $\xi_r^\dagger \ B_r \xi_i$ where did they go? last thing I did not understand how is this answer my question. you care to clarify? thanks for trying to help

Comment: First, thanks for checking the indexes. Now they are fixed. Second a complex restriction can be developed into two real restrictions. This is the best way to handle those problems when $B$ is not Hermitian.